# Assigning 1 bit values to a multidimensional array in Verilog?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, verilog

I am writing a Verilog code in which a 1 bit input has to be serially assigned (bit-wise) to a 2D memory. As far as I understand if we make a memory then it can be assigned byte wise (or contiguously) only at run time. Is there any way I can easily fill up a multidimensional array bit wise in Verilog like in C. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 input in,clk;

 reg [7:0] array [0:511];
 reg [8:0] i=9'd 0;
 reg [2:0] j=3'd 0;

 always @ (posedge clk)
   begin
    if (i<=9'd 511)
     begin
     if(j<=3'd 7)
      begin
       array[i][j]<=in;
       j<=j+1;
      end
     else
      j<=0;
     i<=i+1;
     end 
    else
    i<=0;
  end //end always
```

But this is not giving me the desired results in the post-route simulation. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you do realize the `reg [2:0] i` as a range 0 to 7, it will always be less that 511

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Have edited the code. I actually get the following warning when I synthesize the code:                                            
WARNING Xst:653 - Signal <array> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value 00000000.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for `i` & `j` to be above 511 & 7 respectively.  Therefore, `if (i<=9'd 511)` and `if(j<=3'd 7)` will always evaluate to be true and the `else` condition is unreachable.

Furthermore your `i<=i+1;` does not have a condition statement so it will always incroment, updating the array in a diagonal: `[0][0] -> [1][1] -> ... -> [7][7] -> [8][0] -> [9][1] -> ...`. I assume this is undesired.

To fill the byte before changing `i`, you should use something like this:

```
array[i][j] <= in;
if (j == 3'd7) begin
  j <= 3'd0;
  if (i == 9'd511) begin
    i <= 0;
  end
  else begin
   i <= i + 1;
  end
end
else begin
  j <= j + 1;
end
```

Since the addressable range is a power of two, you can simplify the logic

```
array[i][j] <= in;
j <= j + 1;           // Reminder <= is eval now, update later
if (j == 3'd7) begin  // 'j' here has the pre-eval value
  i <= i + 1;
end
```

FYI: you should always run in simulation before post-route. It is way easier to debug RTL and a waveform.

Comment: Okay I tried using the method you described. The problem is the same, behavioral simulation runs perfectly but post-route and RTL are not as desired. I get the warning "WARNING Xst:653 - Signal <array> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value 00000000" when I simulate.

Comment: @qandeel , can you show more of your code? As is, we are assigning but never using (opposite of the synthesis warning). My immediate guess is you are accessing another `array` from another module.

Comment: `module test(in, clk, out1, out2
    );

input in,clk;
output out1, out2;

reg [7:0] array [0:511];
reg [8:0] i=0;
reg [2:0] j=0;

always @ (posedge clk)
 begin
 array[i][j] <= in;
 if (j == 3'd7) 
  begin
   j <= 3'd0;
   if (i == 9'd511) 
    begin
     i <= 0;
    end
   else 
    begin
     i <= i + 1;
    end
 end
 else 
  begin
   j <= j + 1;
  end
 end

assign out1=array[0][0];
assign out2=array[1][1];
  

endmodule `

Comment: Odd, `array` is clearly assigned. Only two bits are used so I'd expect there are other warnings in the log file stating most of `array` been trimmed for optimization. If `in` or `clk` are tide to constants, then I could expect all of `array` to be trimmed. There are no other warnings in the log file?

Comment: Yes there are no other warnings in the Synthesis report. However I am getting these two warnings in the MAP report:                         WARNING LIT:243 - Logical network clk has no load. 
 
WARNING LIT:395 - The above warning message base_net_load_rule is repeated 1 more times for the following (max. 5 shown): in To see the details of these warning messages, please use the -detail switch.

Comment: are unpacked arrays supported in Verilog 2001?

Comment: Unpacked arrays are supported on all IEEE versions of Verilog (1995, 2001, 2005) as a memory structure. Meaning you can define and use it in a module but it cannot be passed through a port list. FPGAs may have a limitation with large unpacked arrays and therefore need to use a RAM macro module instead.

Comment: I did try your code on [EDAplaygroud](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5FNq) with Yosys 0.3.0. For some reason it didn't like `arrays[i][j] <= in`, but if I loaded the bits into a temporary values it was okay `arrays[i] <= {in,tmp}`. Yosys did remove/optimize-out `array[2]` through `array[511]` which made sense.

Comment: So this means that we essentially have to assign the array (if it is large??) like a packed one, like in the method you mentioned.